# Multiprocessing does not seem to work on df.apply()

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading

I've a pandas dataframe on which I want to apply row operations for several columns. The function that returns the pandas Series I need looks like this:

```
def get_info_previous_flight(row, original_column_name, new_column_name):
if row['n_flight_of_day'] == 1:
    return 0
else:
    flight_date = row['dep_sched_date']
    ac_registration = row['ac_registration']
    previous_flight_number = row['n_flight_of_day'] - 1
    value_previous_flight = flight_info_df.loc[
        (flight_info_df['ac_registration'] == ac_registration) &
        (flight_info_df['dep_sched_date']  == flight_date) &
        (flight_info_df['n_flight_of_day'] == previous_flight_number)
    ][['leg_no', original_column_name]]
    output = pd.Series({'leg_no': value_previous_flight['leg_no'], new_column_name: value_previous_flight[original_column_name]})
    return output
```

The function that I use to perform this tasks for multiple columns is as follows:

```
def perform_task(parameters):
    return parameters[2].apply(lambda row: get_info_previous_flight(row, parameters[0], 
           parameters[1]), axis=1)
```

If I create a pool like this, it does not seem to work:

```
    previous_flight_info = {'change_reason_code_previous_flight': 'change_reason_code',
                        'dep_delay_previous_flight': 'dep_delay',
                        'act_trans_time_previous_flight': 'trans_time',
                        'sched_trans_time_previous_flight': 'sched_trans_time',
                        'act_groundtime_previous_flight': 'Act Groundtime',
                        'sched_groundtime_previous_flight': 'Sched Groundtime'}

tasks = [(key, value, flight_info_df) for key, value in previous_flight_info.items()]
         
pool = mp.Pool()

results = pool.map(perform_task, tasks)
pool.close()
pool.join()

print(results)
```

The thing is, if I perform this .apply() function for each key item combination in the `previous_flight_info` it takes about 3 minutes to run. If I use above example, I don't see any increase in CPU usage and my kernel eventually times out.

Comment: Yep, multiprocessing won't work because each process will have its own copy of the dataframe, and changes won't propagate into the parent process.

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly, you want to fill in the data of a previous flight for each row; you should probably ask a question about how to efficiently do _that_ (and I think `groupby` will be the answer there).

Comment: And now that I look at it, you're also doing a whole lot of extra work since you do the finding-the-previous-flight work separately for each column to be computed.

Comment: You are correct. I'm not sure how 'groupby' will help me here. Can you explain how you would do that? @AKX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`multiprocessing` won't work because each process will have its own copy of the dataframe, and changes won't propagate into the parent process.

Instead of doing a whole lot of work with `apply`, you could do something with `groupby`.

The idea here is to sort the original dataframe so flights are in order, then group it by the pairs used for figuring out previous flights (`(dep_sched_date, ac_registration)` tuples), and then you can simply assign from each group:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.width = 0

flight_info_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "dep_sched_date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02"],
        "ac_registration": ["B-1234", "B-1234", "B-1234", "B-1234", "B-2345", "B-2345", "B-2345"],
        "n_flight_of_day": [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3],
        "dep_delay": [7, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0.6, -8],
        "meals": ["beef", "chicken", "vegetarian", "just cheese", "soup", "tart", "beef"],
    }
)

flight_info_df.sort_values(
    ["dep_sched_date", "ac_registration", "n_flight_of_day"], inplace=True
)
grouped = flight_info_df.groupby(["dep_sched_date", "ac_registration"])

flight_info_df["prev_dep_delay"] = grouped["dep_delay"].shift(1)
flight_info_df["prev_meals"] = grouped["meals"].shift(1)

print(flight_info_df)
```

This prints out

```
  dep_sched_date ac_registration  n_flight_of_day  dep_delay        meals  prev_dep_delay  prev_meals
0     2020-01-01          B-1234                1        7.0         beef             NaN         NaN
1     2020-01-01          B-1234                2        3.0      chicken             7.0        beef
2     2020-01-02          B-1234                1        5.0   vegetarian             NaN         NaN
3     2020-01-02          B-1234                2        2.0  just cheese             5.0  vegetarian
4     2020-01-02          B-2345                1        0.0         soup             NaN         NaN
5     2020-01-02          B-2345                2        0.6         tart             0.0        soup
6     2020-01-02          B-2345                3       -8.0         beef             0.6        tart
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the job much faster indeed. One more question, is there anyway I can use similar logic for getting the cumulative values here? So for example, for the third flight of ac B-2345 I want the value -8 + 0.6 = -7.4 as value. Is that also possible?

Comment: Absolutely: `flight_info_df["cum_dep_delay"] = grouped["dep_delay"].cumsum()`